# Passing a PHP variable into a Javascript funtion

Tags: javascript, php

I have a variable named $path. I want to pass this variable from PHP to a javascript function.

```
<button onclick='myFunctionContact(\"" . $row1['id'] . "\")'>
    <img border='0' alt='Contacts' src='".$imgpth."peoplesmall.png'>
</button>
<script>
function myFunctionContact(id) {
    window.open('!!!$path should go here!!!'+id, '', 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=200,left=500,width=400,height=400');
}
</script>
```

How do I get the URL in path to display inside of the function, in the desired place?

I tried printing the variable into a javascript variable and then placing that variable into the function, but the popup window no longer works when I do that.

```
function myFunctionContact(id) {
    var test1 = <?php echo $path; ?>;
    window.open(test1 +id, '', 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=200,left=500,width=400,height=400');
 }
```

I Know I am doing it wrong, but I have no idea how. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you printing the ; at the end of that echo?

Comment: That is a typo. I'll edit to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: The path needs to be a quoted string. The end result of your echoed string has to, itself, contain quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is how you are echo the path:

Instead of:

```
var test1 = <?php echo $path; ?>
```

i think it should be

```
var test1 = <?php echo '"'.$path.'";'; ?>
```

Comment: Is there a reason it works fine with var myValue = <?php echo json_encode($path); ?>; ?

Comment: json_encode return a string with the "  (double quotes) character, thats whats missing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a hidden input field, and set it's value to whatever you need to be used in your JS code, then grab that value of in your JS, or maybe try an ajax call to get the value you need.

Comment: using a hidden input field is really bad practice. It works though.

Answer (score 0):

json_encode() fixed the problem.

```
var myValue = <?php echo json_encode($path); ?>;
```

Comment: Json is not meant to encode values to be inputted into a javascript variable. `json !== var`

Answer (score 0):

The path needs to be a quoted string. The end result of your echoed string has to, itself, contain quotes.

Assuming `$path` is a string, `window.open` is expecting a quoted string as the parameter.

```
function myFunctionContact(id) {
    window.open(' . $path . ' + id, '', 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=200,left=500,width=400,height=400');
}
</script>
```